# What determines if the casimir effect pushes or pulls

Tags: casimir-effect

I've read an article where chinese researchers have made a mechanism that uses the casimir effect to push two things apart but i'm confused by this cause i've only ever heard of the casimir effect pulling things together why in this case does it push them apart.

Link to article ---> https://phys.org/news/2017-04-harness-mysterious-casimir-tiny-devices.html

Comment: Casimir forces can be repulsive, depending on geometry of surfaces, and composition of layers. See section 3 here: https://www.rug.nl/research/zernike/education/topmasternanoscience/ns190_2016_putten_maikel_van.pdf

Comment: See also surprising result by Timothy Boyer, where Casimir force on perfectly conducting sphere elements tends to expand the sphere, rather than collapse it: http://web.mit.edu/kardar/www/research/seminars/Casimir/PR-Boyer68.pdf

Comment: thank you so much i waited hours for this thank you